# Using pathauto to create multiple aliases, one for each term?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

If I have a taxonomy `tags` so that I can tag a node with `foo` and `bar` and `baz`, is there any way to make the [pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module create three aliases?

If it would normally create `content/my-new-node`, is it possible to make pathauto create `foo/my-new-node` and `bar/my-new-node` and `baz/my-new-node`?

Comment: I have the same issue today.

Comment: Pathauto only handle a single alias per entity. There is no way to make it create three different aliases for the same node.

Answer (score -1):

Under Configuration, if you go to Modules and click on Configure for Pathauto, you should see the option for the URL patterns. There is a section for taxonomy as well. *However*, I realize you want to change a node's URL based on the taxonomy term you've associated with it. At this point, it's just a matter of figuring out what token is going to do that for you.I have not used it, but I would imagine the [Field Tokens](https://www.drupal.org/node/691078) module may help you do what you want to do. If you search for "pathauto" on that page, some people discuss using it with Pathauto down in the comments.

Comment: The OP specifically ask for a solution to create multiple aliases for a single node, using pathauto. This answer fails to address this.